# How to remove all javascript in a theme wordpress?

Tags: plugins, themes

I have a theme name is mytheme
in `themes/mythem/functions.php` I using code:

```
function remove_scripts() {
   remove_action('wp_head','mytheme_head_scripts');
}
add_action('init', 'remove_scripts');
```

=>but result can't remove all javascript, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either use the `admin_*/wp_print_scripts` hook or the `admin_*/wp_print_styles` hook. The styles hook comes before the print scripts hook, so maybe it fits better than just using a priority of `0` for the `*_print_scripts` hook (there might be function with a name that's hooked in earlier on priority `0`).

```
function wpse61635_remove_all_scripts()
{
    global $wp_scripts;
    $leave_alone = array(
        // Put the scripts you don't want to remove in here.
    );

    foreach ( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle )
    {
        // Here we skip/leave-alone those, that we added above ↑
        if ( in_array( $handle, $leave_alone ) )
            continue;

        $wp_scripts->remove( $handle );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'wpse61635_remove_all_scripts', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function `mytheme_head_scripts` used priority while hooking into `wp_head` then you must set your `remove_action` with same priority.

**Example -**

```
function remove_scripts() {
   remove_action('wp_head','mytheme_head_scripts',10);
}
add_action('init', 'remove_scripts');
```